# I have code which is generating word documnt with some data.I need a docs template which have some logo and need to incorporate data in this template

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a code which is generating a word document with some data .
Now I need a docs template which have some logo and need to incorporate data in this template.
How can we do that? loading a template in Salesforce aura and  writing data into it

```js
downloadWordDocument: function(component, event, helper) {
    var lead = component.get("v.lead");
    var fields = [
        { name: 'Name', value: lead.Name },
        { name: 'Email', value: lead.Email },
        { name: 'Phone', value: lead.Phone },
        { name: 'Description Text', value: lead.Description },
        { name: 'Area Of Strength', value: lead.Candidate_Comments__c },
        { name: 'Resume Text', value: lead.Resume_Text__c }
    ];
    var content = '';
        
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        content += '<span style="color: blue;">' + fields[i].name + ':</span><br/><br/>' + fields[i].value + '<br/><br/>';
    }
    var blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' });
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
        var base64data = reader.result;
        var action = component.get("c.saveFile");
        action.setParams({
            fileName: lead.Name + '.docx',
            base64Data: base64data,
            contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
            parentId: lead.Id
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var fileId = response.getReturnValue();
                // Do something with fileId if necessary
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Success",
                    "message": "Word document created and saved.",
                    "type": "success"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            } else {
                // Handle errors
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Error",
                    "message": "An error occurred while creating the Word document.",
                    "type": "error"
                });
                toastEvent.fire();
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write a full solution for you, but I will try to point you in the right direction. First, you really should consider an official SDK to help you write your file. At a glance, it seems that [OpenXmlSdkJs](https://github.com/conveyGmbH/OpenXmlSdkJs) is one such resource you might be able to lean on. Second, I suggest you read [ECMA-376](https://ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-376/) so you understand what you're getting in to.

To include images, you're going to have to have their data stored somewhere, because they needed to be included in the final binary data. OpenXML format is normally a ZIP file. It will contain a master file for the XML, and include folders and files that contain binary data that should appear in the documentation.

If you want to take a look at the data internally, create a new Word document, paste an image into it, and save the file. After saving, rename the extension to .zip, and then open the file. When I do this, I get the following files:

```
./docProps
./docProps/app.xml
./docProps/core.xml
./word
./word/document.xml
./word/fontTable.xml
./word/media
./word/media/image1.png
./word/settings.xml
./word/styles.xml
./word/theme
./word/theme/theme1.xml
./word/webSettings.xml
./word/_rels
./word/_rels/document.xml.rels
./[Content_Types].xml
./_rels
./_rels/.rels
```

At minimum, you're going to want to see how these files are built and try to emulate them. It is a lot of material to cover, but not incredibly difficult once you know what you're doing. Again, I recommend a JS library to help you out with this task.